# Find the number of couples with the same difference in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This is a interview Question.

"Given a sorted array. Find the number of couples with the same difference."

for example: if array is {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 7 , 8, 9};

then we have

5 pairs with difference of 1

6 pairs with difference of 2

4 pairs with difference of 4

2 pairs with difference of 3

4 pairs with difference of 6

3 pairs with difference of 5

2 pairs with difference of 7

1 pair with difference of  8

1 pair with difference of  0

I tried the following:

```
maxdiff=arr[n-1]-arr[0];  //calculating the maximum difference
int b[maxdiff];
for(i=0;i<maxdiff;i++)
{
 for(j=0;j<n;j++)
 {
  p=arr[j]+i;
  x=binarysearch(p,arr);    //search p in array,where x return 0/1
  if(x==1)
  b[i]++;
 }
}
```

this is O(k*n*logn) solution where k is the maximum difference between the first and last element of a sorted array,n is the array size.

Does anyone have any better idea than this?

Comment: You should include "difference of 0" and "difference of 8", too.

Comment: You can use HashMap rather than array, then the binary search can be replaced by normal search in HashMap which is O(1)

Comment: An alternative approach is to compute the autocorrelation of the histogram using the FFT in O(n+k.logk)

Comment: What is the format of result? Do you need list number of couples for each difference?

Comment: @ari Yes,i just need to output the number of couples for each difference.

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong and should be modified a bit. If you have a lot of numbers with the same value, you should find the number of elements with value `n-k` for each `k` (this can be done with one extra binary search easily) and it will still remain `O(nk*logN)`

Comment: @Vishu then you can't get better solution than one presented below by Mike Hartl. To get better solution you would have to increase number of couples for some difference by more than one.

Comment: @Ari:that's what i am asking a general solution not just the example i had given

Comment: @Ari This is plain wrong, the approach suggested here (with my suggestion how to fix it) will be MUCH better then the naive `O(n^2)` if the array is large and consists of elements close to each other.

Comment: @amit Yes, but for array `arr = {0, 100000000}` it will be much worse. Generally I believe that we can assume that maxdiff is about `O(n)`, so your solution will work in `O((n^2) log n)`.

Comment: Note that the solution asks you to *count* the number of such couples. You do not need to enumerate all possible cases in order to count them! See Ivan's answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems unnecessarily complicated and I don't fully see what you are doing. Is the problem not solved by just:

```
maxdiff=arr[n-1]-arr[0];  //calculating the maximum difference
int b[maxdiff];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<i;j++) // note: <i instead of <n
   {
      b[arr[i]-arr[j]]++
   }
}
```

This is O(n**2).

BTW, you didn't list the one pair with a difference of 8 or the one pair with a difference of 0. On purpose?

*Edit:*

The logic is just: look at each pair in the original array. Each pair forms a difference. Increase the counter for that difference.

*Edit 2:*

On your request, here are my test results:

```
C:\src>a
diff: 0 pairs: 1
diff: 1 pairs: 5
diff: 2 pairs: 6
diff: 3 pairs: 2
diff: 4 pairs: 4
diff: 5 pairs: 3
diff: 6 pairs: 4
diff: 7 pairs: 2
diff: 8 pairs: 1
```

As well as the complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int n=8;
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,5,7,7,8,9};
  int i, j;

  int maxdiff=arr[n-1]-arr[0];  //calculating the maximum difference
  int b[maxdiff];

  for(i=0;i<=maxdiff;i++)
    {
      b[i]=0;
    }  

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<i;j++) // note: <i instead of <n
        {
          b[arr[i]-arr[j]]++;
        }
    }

  for (i=0;i<=maxdiff;++i)
    cout<<"diff: "<<i<<" pairs: "<<b[i]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand the logic. can you run some test case and post result. bit confusing

Comment: The outer for loop might give invalid array indexes.

Comment: `It seems unnecessarily complicated` For large arrays where their values are relatively close to each other - this "unnecessarily complicated" approach will be MUCH more efficient then your naive approach/

Comment: @amit I think it's wrong as well though as it counts duplicate values only once while the test data implies that they must be counted twice. So if you want to count *all* the differences, you need to go back to the naive approach, don't you?

Comment: @MikeHartl I commented about it on the question itself, it is easy to fix (I explained how in my comment).

Comment: You could use a `Map` from `int` to `int` (or whatever the construct is called in cpp) instead of an array with counts. If `maxdiff` is huge, that is much more memory efficient.

Answer (score 5):

This can be solved in O(k*log k) (where k is a maximal difference) if you use [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) for multiplication of polynomials.

Consider the following problem: having two sets A = a_1, ..., a_n and B = b_1, ..., b_m, for each X find the number of pairs (i, j) such that a_i + b_j = X. It can be solved as follows.

Let Pa = x**a_1 + ... + x**a_n, Pb = x**b_1 + ... + x**b_m. If you look at Pa * Pb, you may find that the coefficient for x**R is an answer for the problem where X = R. So, multiply this polynomials using Fourier transform, and you will find the answer for every X in O(n*log n).

Afterwards, your problem may be reduced to this one saying A = arr_1, ..., arr_n, B = -arr_1, ..., -arr_n and shifting (adding a constant) to every value of A and B to make them lay between 0 and k.

Comment: Sometimes I don't understand SO, you have the best answer by far but I think most people don't take the time to understand it so it goes ignored .... (Basically you are using a generating function to do the counting for you, a great solution.)

Comment: @ldog The post claims this is both O(n*log n) and O(k*log k) where k is the maximal distance. I believe the latter is true, and that makes this worse than the brute force O(n^2) approach unless k is sufficiently small. In those cases it may well be worth the added complexity, but it doesn't seem to blow the brute force approach out of the water. Still, a nice result.

Comment: @ldog Obviously an answer that's very easy to understand is expected to be upvoted more than an answer that could require significant time to understand, regardless of whether or not the latter is better. Not to mention that this answer is 8 hours older, which tends to make a big difference. And while I do like great answers, I can't spend the whole day reading up on things to understand them.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be solved in better than O(n^2) for general input arrays because some inputs lead to O(n^2) different outputs. E.g., it's easy to construct an array where every pair of elements has a different separation.

---

The question makes more sense if it's asking for the number of pairs that have some specified separation. That can be done in linear time, and uses the fact that the array's sorted. Doesn't really make sense to give a sorted array if the best we can do is slower than sorting.